# Adding or Replacing text within hyperlinks

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, find-and-replace, vbscript

I am very confused after trying to explore how this can be done. Its very simple but yet cant find a solution.

What I wish to know is the following. I have three separate documents, all of which are linked to some degree; the data is inputted from a document (1. master input) and summarised into the three spreadsheets.

Each document is identically laid out the only variable factors are the dates and for the master input, we have numerical values.

In an illustration form it looks like this:

a. 1 Master input --> (feeds into) 2,3
b. 2 --> (feeds into) 3 and 4
c. 3 --> (feeds into) 4

What I wish to know is, in document 2,3 and 4....the data changes every year. I have many 'hyperlinks' of the spreadsheet as an example:

2015 = *" \Daily Revenue\2015[Revenue 2015.xls]Year Summary'!$C$160"*

2016 = *" \Daily Revenue\2016[Revenue 2016.xls]Year Summary'!$C$160"*

2017 = *" \Daily Revenue\2017[Revenue 2017.xls]Year Summary'!$C$160"*

From the above the only variable that I need to change is the year, is there any code/macro etc I can use to replace the **YEAR** within the hyperlink. Consider in mind the file path will **always** remain the same.

I am fully aware of the *find and replace* function however I wish to make this user friendly and easy.

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: This is not a code writing service. I recommend you experiment with Excel's built-in macro recorder to get started. If you get stuck come back, post what you've tried, and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you keep talking about hyperlinks. I think what you mean are formulas that reference other files. Those are not hyperlinks. Here's the solution if what you really meant was hyperlinks:

---

To answer your actual question: Yes, there is a macro for that. Sure. I think what you need to know about is the `Worksheet.Hyperlinks` object. You can loop through each hyperlink in each worksheet and replace the address with whatever you want. Here's a snippet example:

```
Sub ChangeHyperlinks()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim hyp As Hyperlink
    For Each hyp In ws.Hyperlinks
        hyp.Address = Replace(hyp.Address, "2015", "2016")
    Next
End Sub
```

You're going to have to modify it if you don't want to change *every* hyperlink by adding conditional statements like `If InStr(1, hyp.Address, "\Daily Revenue\2015") Then`. You could use the `Workbook_Open` event to run every time the file is opened, grab the right year based on the file's name, and then run the replace for the hyperlinks. Yes, this would fire *every* time the file is opened even if it's already correct. Depending on how many hyperlinks you have, this could be fine or it could grind everything to a halt.

---

And here's a code snippet if what you really meant was formulas. Again, you'll have to adapt it more to your needs but this should get you started.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim srcArray As Variant
    srcArray = ThisWorkbook.LinkSources(xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
    For i = 1 To UBound(srcArray)
        Debug.Print srcArray(i)
        ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink srcArray(i), Replace(srcArray(i), "2015", "2016")
    Next
End Sub
```

Also, if you meant formulas, then your question is a duplicate from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28588857/4475014).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ambiguities in your question.  This answer assumes you're talking about cell references in other workbooks, as illustrated in your examples, rather than hyperlinks, and that the task is to set up the references as adjustable by year, rather than rewrite all of the formulas each year.

First, you need a year reference somewhere.  It isn't clear when or in what manner you want the year to change (automatically on January 1 of each year?  On a date of your choosing?  You want the ability to change the year at any time?).  So I'll base this on a generic solution.  Pick a cell to hold the year reference.  For my example, I'll use cell `Z1` of the worksheet that contains the cell references in your example.  If you want the ability to change the year at will or on a date of your choosing, just enter in `Z1` the four digit year.  If you want the year to change automatically on January 1, use `=YEAR(TODAY())`.

Then, instead of hard coding the year into each formula, concatenate a reference to `Z1` and use the INDIRECT function to convert the text string to a cell reference.  For example:

```
          '\Daily Revenue\2015[Revenue 2015.xls]Year Summary'!$C$160   becomes
INDIRECT("'\Daily Revenue\"&Z1&"[Revenue "&Z1&".xls]Year Summary'!$C$160")
```

With an existing worksheet, you would need to make a one-time change to modify the cell references.  After that, you can change the year whenever you want by changing the `Z1` entry.